# Count of AWS Lambda invocations seems too low

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an API Gateway with a custom authorizer, which manages rate limiting for my API layer.

Therefore, it cannot be cached as it has to calculate if a requester has reached their rate limit on every API call.

As this authorizer is called before any request, I would assume that around 50% of all invocations in the API would be from this authorizer.

However, in CloudWatch metrics I am noticing only 20,000 invocations per month for this authorizer. Meanwhile the metrics in the APIs consumer is telling me I have 90K monthly active users.

Another bit of evidence to suggest this number is wrong, is that the graph for API Gateway Count does not look anything like the Authorizer invocations, I would expect for these curves to at least look the same shape as the authorizer should be called on every request to the API.

This is confimed by going into the console into `API Gateway > APIs > api-name > authorizers > Authorization Caching: Authorization not cached`

AWS defines an invocation as:

> Invocations – The number of times that your function code is invoked,
> including successful invocations and invocations that result in a
> function error. Invocations aren't recorded if the invocation request
> is throttled or otherwise results in an invocation error. The value of
> Invocations equals the number of requests billed.
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html

Does anyone have any idea whatg might cause this discrepency?

Comment: Is there a particular reason to not use Amazon API Gateway rate limiting feature? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html